# Sub nav not showing

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to work out why the sub nav on the right hand side bar is not showing I have tried changing and adding borders and also `z-index` but I cannot get any life out of the dropdowns

http://www.smithprint.co.nz/product-category/finishing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because your li is inside `#sidebar` that you set with `overflow: hidden;`
just remove or comment the css `overflow: hidden;` for `#sidebar` ( there are 2 occurrences of it )

Answer (score 2):

Remove overflow on #sidebar.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using `overflow: hidden;` on `#sidebar`